# Popup window / message for remaining time

Tags: vb.net

I have several froms in my application.  When application starts, a timer starts for 30 minutes.
I want to show the remaining time using a popup window, message or whatever, on whichever form the user is at that time.

Please advise how to do it.

Thanks
Furqan

Comment: What you are asking for is an entire application.  What have you tried already?  What has worked?  What hasn't?  Do some research on timers & events.

Answer (score 0):

The timer objects in the .net framework do not give access to the time already elapsed or remaining.

However when your application starts you will can create and start a stop watch.

```
private _sw as System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew()
```

At any time you can then call the following code which you can subtract from your 30 minutes

```
_sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds
```

To show this time constantly on  a form you may need a second timer to update the screen that queries this value.